# Build a narrow archway

Tags: design, castle

Is there a way to make a more narrow v-shaped arch as in picture below? I looked at the arches section on Bricklink and they all look like they're too broad.

[image]

Comment: I wonder, if I could use the Slope, Curved 6 x 1 Inverted (part #42023). Perhaps I could place 2 of them vertically so they split at the top and then use other similar parts somehow.

Comment: This looks like it could be two arch pieces placed at right angles, and then the low camera angle/viewport gives it a more narrow visual effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of [Brick, Arch 1 x 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13965#T=C) pieces produce somewhat similar archway.

[image]